# Why are we using pointer to pointer for one and a normal pointer to another?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

```
// A complete working C++ program to demonstrate
// all insertion methods on Linked List
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// A linked list node
class Node
{
    public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer)
to the head of a list and an int, inserts
a new node on the front of the list. */
void push(Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* 1. allocate node */
    Node* new_node = new Node();

    /* 2. put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data;

    /* 3. Make next of new node as head */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);

    /* 4. move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}

/* Given a node prev_node, insert a new node after the given
prev_node */
void insertAfter(Node* prev_node, int new_data)
{
    /*1. check if the given prev_node is NULL */
    if (prev_node == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"The given previous node cannot be NULL";
        return;
    }

    /* 2. allocate new node */
    Node* new_node = new Node();

    /* 3. put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data;

    /* 4. Make next of new node as next of prev_node */
    new_node->next = prev_node->next;

    /* 5. move the next of prev_node as new_node */
    prev_node->next = new_node;
}

/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head
of a list and an int, appends a new node at the end */
void append(Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* 1. allocate node */
    Node* new_node = new Node();

    Node *last = *head_ref; /* used in step 5*/

    /* 2. put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data;

    /* 3. This new node is going to be
    the last node, so make next of
    it as NULL*/
    new_node->next = NULL;

    /* 4. If the Linked List is empty,
    then make the new node as head */
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
    {
        *head_ref = new_node;
        return;
    }

    /* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
    while (last->next != NULL)
    {
        last = last->next;
    }

    /* 6. Change the next of last node */
    last->next = new_node;
    return;
}

// This function prints contents of
// linked list starting from head
void printList(Node *node)
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        cout<<" "<<node->data;
        node = node->next;
    }
}

/* Driver code*/
int main()
{
    /* Start with the empty list */
    Node* head = NULL;
    
    // Insert 6. So linked list becomes 6->NULL
    append(&head, 6);
    
    // Insert 7 at the beginning.
    // So linked list becomes 7->6->NULL
    push(&head, 7);
    
    // Insert 1 at the beginning.
    // So linked list becomes 1->7->6->NULL
    push(&head, 1);
    
    // Insert 4 at the end. So
    // linked list becomes 1->7->6->4->NULL
    append(&head, 4);
    
    // Insert 8, after 7. So linked
    // list becomes 1->7->8->6->4->NULL
    insertAfter(head->next, 8);
    
    cout<<"Created Linked list is: ";
    printList(head);
    
    return 0;
}


// from geeksforgeek
```

Why the `append` and `push` function have a pointer to pointer (head_ref), but the `insertAfter` function has a normal pointer (prev_node)? As we are changing them whether it is the head or the previous node, so it should be same approach(types of pointer).

Can I use a normal pointer instead of a pointer to pointer for the same?

Comment: `insertAfter()` does not modify the `prev_node` parameter. So it's passed by value. The other functions do modify the parameter, so it's passed by reference (in this case as a pointer to pointer which is the C-style of passing by reference, in C++ style it would have been reference to pointer, not pointer to pointer.)

Comment: Because we're writing C code and not C++.

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: so can I use just pointer instead of reference to pointer?

Comment: In c++ you should use `void append(Node* & head_ref, int new_data)` instead of `void append(Node** head_ref, int new_data)` the latter is the `c` way because `c` does not have reference parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions `push` and `append` both need to be able to change the pointer to the head node.

If they were only passed a `Node*` pointing to the head, then they would only be able to change their local copy of that pointer to the head node. However, they need to be able to change the original pointer to the head node, which is the variable `head` in the function `main`. That is why they need a pointer to the variable `head` in the function `main`, so both functions need to be passed a `Node**`.

In contrast to the functions `push` and `append`, the function `insertAfter` will never need to change the pointer that is being passed to the function. That is why it is sufficient to pass a `Node*`.

Comment: but ```insertAfter``` function changing the value of the ```prev_node->next``` that should be changed in ```main``` function as well.

Comment: But it does not alter the `prev_node`  pointer so that is fine.

Comment: @user14070533: Yes, you are correct that the effect of `prev_node->next` will be visible in the function `main` as well. That is because the function `insertAfter` does not have its own local copy of `prev_node->next`. It only has its own local copy of `prev_node`. Therefore, changing `prev_node` would not be visible in the function `main`, but changing `prev_node->next` is visible in `main`.

Comment: @user14070533: You may want to read about the difference between passing variables to a function [by value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_value.htm), [by pointer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_pointer.htm) and [by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm).

Comment: @user14070533: You must be aware that, unless you are using C++ references, only values are passed to functions, not variables. Therefore, when you think you are passing a variable to a function, you are actually passing a copy of the value of a variable to a function. For this reason, if that function changes this copy, it won't be changing the original variable. If you want the function to be able to change the original variable, you must instead pass a pointer or a reference to the original variable. That will allow the function to also change the original variable.

Comment: @user14070533: My last comment is a repost of one of my previous comments. I made some corrections and reposted my comment, because I was unable to edit it. Editing is only possible within 5 minutes of posting the comment. So don't be surprised if my last comment appears familiar to you.